# Pandas group by time interval (5min, 10min, 1day, 1year) and count amount of entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a simple pandas dataframe with around 10000 to 20000 entries for each day. This dataframe contains a point and a datetime (datetime64). For example, it looks like this:

```
        point   timestamp_local
0       A       2018-09-29 00:00:20
1       A       2018-09-29 00:04:34
2       A       2018-09-29 00:06:59
3       B       2018-09-29 00:11:09
4       B       2018-09-29 01:19:28
...     ...     ...
24282   B       2018-09-29 21:40:26
24283   C       2018-09-29 21:40:31
24284   C       2018-09-29 21:45:17
24285   A       2018-09-29 22:20:29
24286   B       2018-09-29 22:28:08
```

What I now what to get is a dataframe which groups the dataframe above by point and a interval I want to specify and also counts the amount of entries for each point of the interval. Also the interval should be for example a 5 min. interval, a 10 min. interval or also 1 interval on a daily, monthly or yearly base.

This is what I got so far to segment the interval:

```
df['10min_period'] = df.apply(lambda x: "period_%d"%(int(x[1].minute/10) + 1), axis=1)
```

This returns:

```
    point   timestamp_local         10min_period
0   A       2018-09-29 00:00:20     period_1
1   B       2018-09-29 00:04:34     period_1
2   B       2018-09-29 00:06:59     period_1
3   C       2018-09-29 00:11:09     period_2
4   C       2018-09-29 01:19:28     period_2
```

And this counts the periods:

```
df = df.groupby([df['point'], df['10min_period']]).agg(['count'])
```

This returns the following dataframe:

```
                           timestamp_local
point   10min_period       count
A       period_1           2092
        period_2           2437
        period_3           2181
        period_4           2525
        period_5           2325
        period_6           2317
B       period_1           1814
        period_2           1719
        period_3           1732
        period_4           1575
        period_5           1789
        period_6           1781
...     ...                ...
```

But this is not exactly what I want. The reason for this is that the period row entries are wrong. My code has segmented the periods in 10 minute intervals **independent** from the year, month, date and hour. **That is exactly what I don't want!**

I want to have a dateframe which segmented by an interval I have specified, e.g. 5 min. , 10 min., 1 day, 1 year and so on **but considers** the year, month, day, hour and minute! (Take a look on how the periods are named!)

```
I give you an example of what I want:
        point   timestamp_local         10min_period
    0   A       2018-09-29 00:00:20     period_2018-09-29_00:00:00
    1   B       2018-09-29 00:04:34     period_2018-09-29_00:00:00
    2   B       2018-09-29 00:06:59     period_2018-09-29_00:00:00
    3   C       2018-09-29 00:11:09     period_2018-09-29_00:10:00
    4   C       2018-09-29 00:19:28     period_2018-09-29_00:10:00
    5   A       2018-09-29 00:00:20     period_2018-09-29_00:00:00
    6   B       2018-09-30 01:04:34     period_2018-09-30_01:00:00
    7   B       2018-09-30 00:06:59     period_2018-09-30_00:00:00
    8   C       2018-10-29 02:15:09     period_2018-10-29_02:15:00
    9   C       2019-09-29 01:19:28     period_2019-09-29_01:10:00
```

Its very imported to name the period that way so I know to which day and interval the entry contains. How can I do this? And for exmaple if it would have been a 5 minute interval the period should be named like `period_2018-09-29_00:00:00`, `period_2018-09-29_00:05:00` and `period_2018-09-29_00:25:00` and so on and so on.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this, for minute intervals:

```
df.groupby(['point',df.timestamp_local.dt.floor('5Min')]).size()
```

and this, for month/year

```
df.groupby(['point', df.timestamp_local.dt.to_period('M')]).size()
```

Comment: Yes perfect! This is what I where looking for. Just one question: How is the row named with the counts and can I rename it to something like counts? Pandas is showing me just a `0` as the row name.

Comment: Also, how can I plot this as a line chart grouped by point? (so one line for each point)

Comment: Because this is now a `MultiIndex` I cannot access the points anymore by `df[df[point == 'a']]`... How can I 'convert' that to a normal DataFrame again?

Comment: That's a lot of additional question without much details on what you expect. I don't think I can address them in the comments :-).